# How to fix opening empty Excel instance changing StartUp-path XLSTART and PERSONAL.XLSB?

Tags: excel, vba

Default startup location Excel was XLSTART with personal workbook PERSONAL.XSLB.

Change1: Startup location M:/Template/Div, in this folder only PERSONAL.XSLB located.
This gived no probem, Excel starts normally with empty sheet with PERSONAL.XLSB available (have renamed the CodeModuleNaam to "PersonalWorkbook")

Change2: I have changed the name of the personal workbook from PERSONAL.XLSB to MULTILEVEL.XLSB in the same location from change1 (M:/Template/Div).
Problem: If I open Excel-application, I see an empty instance (Ribbon>View>Hide/Unhide does not work). If I open an existing Excel-file, then Excel opens also an empty Excel-instance in de background. If I close the Excel-file, the instance is still open.
Normally there is only one Excel instance open with OR the opened Excel-file, OR a blank sheet.

If I only change the name of the personal workbook back from MULTILEVEL.XLSB tot PERSONAL.XLSB, then this problem does not occur. However, I do want to use the name of MULTILEVEL.XLSB.

I am very gratefull for your help! If any additional information is required, I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see is to open your `MULTILEVEL.XLSB` in the `Workbook_Open()`-event of the (apart from the code for that event) empty `PERSONAL.XLSB`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that multiple users have a Personal.XLSB. Hence the different name of this workbook.

Comment: Isn't the Personal.xlsb stored in each user's personal AppData-Folder?

Comment: No I have removed the XLSTART folders at the users (including my own XLSTART folders)